# Rocketchat Installation Wizard Hangs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, chat, rocket.chat

I'm trying to use rocketchat with docker compose but the wizard is stuck at the first stage.
Steps I took

mkdir /tmp/rocketchat
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/develop/docker-compose.yml -o docker-compose.yml
docker-compose up -d

Go to url http://localhost:3000

Then use the wizard to finish the install. The api call hangs and timeouts after several minutes. Once I refresh the page I'm redirected to the connexion page

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Got this too.

I was able to go around by setting the admin at the docker file:

```
environment:
  - ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
  - ADMIN_PASS=MYPASSWORD
  - OVERWRITE_SETTING_Accounts_SystemBlockedUsernameList=administrator,system,user
```

this will skip the wizard and save you this problem.

**edit**
After 3.18.X, the admin username is reserved, so this will not work, unless you OVERWRITE this settings using - OVERWRITE_SETTING_Accounts_SystemBlockedUsernameList=administrator,system,user

Answer (score 0):

This problem is propably caused by the server trying to send confirmation email to an invalid smtp server because it is not configured. I had the same issue, I solved by creating an account with env variables in docker-compose.yml like the other answer suggested

```
environment:
  - ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
  - ADMIN_PASS=MYPASSWORD
```

and after the login, I configured the smtp connection from the settings.